# When to use object over hashmap

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap

https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/solutions/4127892/beats-99-99-easy-solution-with-o-n-approach-c-python-java-javascript/

I was looking at this solution on Leetcode which uses a "hashmap". I did some research and found there is no official hashmap in javascript but there is a map and an object which differ. I'm still learning the difference between the two.

My question is why was an object used for this example? Is that the correct way of doing it or would it be more professional to use a map?

I thought this would be incorrect because an object is used for storing personalized data but here we're using it like a map.

Comment: Both are hashmaps underneath.

Comment: It’s very much ok to use objects like this.  It’s also ok to use a Map, if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why was an object used for this example? Is that the correct way of doing it or would it be more professional to use a map?

It would be more professional to use a `Map` if you need hash-maps mainly for the following reasons:

- A `Map` does not contain any keys by default. It only contains what is explicitly put into it but An `Object` has a prototype, so it contains default keys that could collide with your own keys if you're not careful.
  Note: This can be bypassed by using `Object.create(null)`, but this is seldom done.
- A `Map`'s keys can be any value (including functions, objects, or any primitive).    The keys of an `Object` must be either a `String` or a `Symbol`.
- A `Map` is an iterable, so it can be directly iterated. And as seen in your example, you need this property.
- A `Map` Performs better in scenarios involving frequent additions and removals of key-value pairs.

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: What are some of the default keys in an object?

Comment: @User9123 `"toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "propertyIsEnumerable", "isPrototypeOf", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__lookupSetter__", "__proto__", "constructor"`.